# piecewise non linear cost function in cplex

Tags: optimization, cplex, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

Is it possible to model a non-linear piece-wise cost function in Cplex?

For example something like the figures I put here:

[image]

[non linear piece wise Cost function (black line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8w0U.png)

I know one way is to linearising the quadratic part to linear one, but, I want to use the quadratic part as it is.

You can see that the condition is on the decision variable itself, the cost function can be formulated as follows:

if x ≲ x0  Then cost is quadratic part;

else cost is linear part.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pick the cheapest curve at x:

```
 min cost
 cost ≥ f(x) − Mδ
 cost ≥ g(x) − M(1−δ)
 δ ϵ {0,1}
```

M is a constant: the largest difference between the two curves (i.e. `M=|f(xmax)−g(xmax)|`). δ is a binary variable. I assumed we are minimizing cost and that the quadratic function is convex.

This construct implements

```
 min cost
 cost ≥ f(x)  or  cost ≥ g(x)
```

The solver will always drop the most expensive function, and keep the cheapest. In your picture this is exactly what we want: on the left of `x0` the quadratic function is the cheapest, and on the right of `x0`, the linear function is cheaper. This formulation will automatically pick the cheaper option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erwin. But, tbh, I don't understand your solution. Would you please elaborate? what is delta? and we want to minimise cost, these are constraints on the objective function itself. My main question is that is it possible to implement such function in Cplex or not?

Comment: Delta is a binary variable. The objective can be "minimize cost" where cost is a continuous variable. Yes, this can be implemented in Cplex (or any other MIP solver).